# How to Call Global Functions from Modules and Maintain Modularity?

Tags: javascript

I am using Svelte with [Ultralight](https://ultralig.ht/), communication is handled with JavaScriptCore so Ultralight set / call functions on the global javascript object (which I believe is window). Now I want to call these functions in my svelte app, but I am using modules and so I can't set / use global functions.

So for now I am stuck to something like this :

`CppInterop.js` module :

```
import { notification } from "./lib/store";

// Expose store globally
window.store = {
    notification
}

// Expose the C++ functions
export default {
    test: () => window.Test()
}
```

`cpp.js` that I include directly in my html file with `<script src="/cpp.js"></script>` :

```
// From JS to C++
window.Test = Test;

// From C++ to JS
function notification(message, type)
{
    window.store.notification.notify(message, type);
}
```

Interop doesn't seems to work then I try to access the functions via `window` so that's why I do `window.Test = Test`. What I would like is to call / define global function while still having access to modules (to call my own functions and stores), is that possible ?

Here is how the C++ set the interop functions :

```
JSValueRef JavascriptInterop::execute(const JSContextRef &ctx, const std::string &functionName, const std::vector<JSValueRef> &args)
{
    JSObject global = JSGlobalObject();
    JSValueRef exception = nullptr;

    JSValueRef function = global[functionName.c_str()];
    if (!JSValueIsObject(ctx, function))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Function not found");
    }

    JSObject functionObj = JSValueToObject(ctx, function, &exception);
    if (exception)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Function not found");
    }

    JSValueRef result = JSObjectCallAsFunction(ctx, functionObj, nullptr, args.size(), args.data(), &exception);

    // Handle any exceptions that were thrown.
    if (exception)
    {
        // Get exception description

    return result;
}

void UIHandler::register_callbacks()
{
    RefPtr<JSContext> context = _view->LockJSContext();
    SetJSContext(context->ctx());
    JSObject global = JSGlobalObject();

    global["Test"] = BindJSCallbackWithRetval(&UIHandler::Test);
}
```

Comment: "*I am using modules and so I can't set / use global functions*" - no, what makes you think that?

Comment: Where does `Test` come from? How does the C++ code call `notification`?

Comment: You might want to look at [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)...

Comment: @Bergi I tried to set the functions with `window.Test = function` but it was not accessible from the C++ interop, retried and it work now so the problem was from somewhere else. @AKX thanks that's better than `window` since VS Code don't do syntax error for `globalThis.Test = function`